# How to find line number by path in monaco-editor (json)?

Tags: monaco-editor

json code:

```
{
  pages: [
    {
      text: 'test'
    }
  ]
}
```

getLineByPath(['pages', 0, 'text']) -> 4

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `getPositionAt(index)` function to find the line number by path.

This is how you can achieve it in js

```
const path = ['pages', 0, 'text']; // Your desired path
const index = model.getValue().indexOf(JSON.stringify(path));
const position = model.getPositionAt(index);

console.log(`Line number for path ${JSON.stringify(path)}: ${position.lineNumber}`);
```

Comment: here index will always be -1, how should this work? I have a large json, need to find a string anywhere